# OS X Ignores DefaultKeyBinding Option+U

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I'm building a DefaultKeyBinding.dict with some useful functions.

One of the functions I'd like is `uppercaseWord:`, but when I try to bind this to Option+U, OS X ignores this binding. It also ignores the other "composing" bindings, Option+I,E etc.

Is there anyway I can make OS X respect my bindings? I know it ignores some of them to ensure applications run properly, but I haven't seen a list of them anywhere. Does it exist?

**EDIT**: It seems dead keys take precedence over bindings. The solution is to remap the dead keys elsewhere so my normal keys will work.

Comment: Have you logged out and back in to load the `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`? Do any combinations with `Option+Character` work? Are these broken combinations  assigned a character with your current keyboard layout (e.g. `Option-S` = `ß` with British layout); what if you use that character instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I can think of would be to use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a custom keyboard layout without the dead key states under option.

Apart from dead keys, there aren't that many key combinations that couldn't be overridden. The only ones I've found are shift-command-arrows, control-option-command-arrows, and command-tab.